# Azure Media services video doesn't play when published with streaming locator

Tags: azure-media-services

I'm trying to use Azure Media Services. For demo purpose I've uploaded a video directly on the portal then clicked to encode this uploaded video in 'Adaptive Streaming' preset.
This scheduled a encoding job which generated another file.
I can't play this video on the portal, when I play I get the following error:

```
A network error caused the video download to fail part-way. 
Please check your network connection or try again later. (0x20200000)
```

[image]